# How to reinitialize an array in C (not C++)?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, object-initializers

How can I reinitialize an array in C?

Should I define it through a pointer: `int *data[]`, or can I just code: `int data[] = {};`?

For example, I have defined it like:

```
int main(void) {
    int data[] = {44, 22, 1, 2, 3, 1000, 3};
```

Now, how do I reinitialize the array `data`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "reinitialize"?

Comment: Do you mean free the old array and reallocate?

Comment: @JerryCoffin I meant exactly reinitializing, once I have created an array , then I want to reinitialize it with its size and members

Answer (score 17):

*Initialization* only occurs once, when you create the array:

```
int foo[] = {0,1,2,3,4}; // creates a 5-element array of int and
                         // initializes it
```

Once the array has been defined, you can assign to individual *elements*:

```
foo[0] = 5;
foo[1] = 4;
foo[2] = 3;
foo[3] = 2;
foo[4] = 1;
```

but you cannot assign to the array itself; IOW, you cannot write something like

```
foo = {5,4,3,2,1};
```

You can, however, use `memcpy` to copy the *contents* of one array to another:

```
int foo[5];
int bar[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int i;

memcpy(foo, bar, sizeof bar); // Copies *contents* of bar to foo

for (i = 0; i < sizeof foo / sizeof *foo; i++)
  printf("foo[%d] = %d\n", i, foo[i]);
```

Similarly, an array created in this manner cannot be resized; its size is fixed at declaration time.  In C89 and earlier, the array size has to be known at compile time - either by specifying the size with a compile-time constant (an integral expression or a macro that expanded to an integral expression) or by using an initializer such as above, from which the array size is computed.

C99 introduced *variable length arrays*, which can be declared using a run-time value, such as:

```
void foo(int x)
{
  int arr[x];
  ...
}
```

Note that, like regular arrays, VLAs cannot be resized after they have been defined.

Alternately, you can dynamically allocate an array using `malloc`, although you cannot initialize it in the manner above:

```
int *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo * N); // where N is the number of elements
```

You can still assign to individual elements:

```
foo[0] = 5;
foo[1] = 4;
foo[2] = 3;
...
```

or you can use `memcpy` as demonstrated above.  Note that you must remember to `free` the array when you're done:

```
free(foo);
```

Arrays created in this manner *can* be resized, using `realloc`:

```
int *tmp = realloc(foo, sizeof *foo * NEW_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS);
if (tmp)
  foo = tmp;
```

Why not just assign the result of `realloc` back to `foo`?  If the `realloc` operation fails, it will return NULL.  If that happens and we assign the result back to `foo`, we lose track of the memory we've already allocated, leading to a memory leak.

C99 introduced an array literal syntax; you can write something like

```
int *foo = (int[]){1,2,3,4,5};
```

and then index into `foo` like an array:

```
printf("foo[%d] = %d\n", i, foo[i]);
```

although I'm pretty sure you *cannot* alter the contents of `foo[i]`, similar to how attempting to alter the contents of a string literal is undefined (although I haven't found chapter and verse on that).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot re-initialize any types as such, definitely not arrays.
Initialization is a one time event, when you provide some value to a variable in the same statement when it is being created.

You could explicitly loop through array and fill it up again if you need to *assign* new values to each of them
OR
Use **[memset()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/memset.html)** or **[memcpy()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/memcpy.html)** for setting all elements to specific value or copying specific elements to it resp.

Comment: How about the reszing array length in pure c in runtime? And how abot free()/realloc() it?

Comment: @user1131997: The length of an array needs to be a compile time constant, So you cannot modify it at run-time.Also, You can resize only an dynamically allocated array by using `realloc()` but that is not re-initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Initialization (if any) must be done during the time of creating a variable. Because, during the compile time, the compiler assigns this value to the variable. Any other assignments after this line is executed during run-time only.

In your case, you can initialize an array during it's creation. The next time you are assigning some value doesn't mean an 'initialization'; rather it's a run-time assignment only.

If you want to create, and store elements dynamically, then you can use pointers to do so.

Comment: reinitialization of array can't be done in pure c in runtime or I muse use pointer, free()/realloc() ?

Comment: `realloc()` will reallocate with a new size. `free()` will clear all allocated memory. In your case, you can `realloc()`

Answer (score 1):

My partial solution for assigning new values (works in **gcc** with **c99**-syntax):

```
#define arr_set(type, arr, ...) { \
    int arr_size = sizeof((type[]){__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(type); \
    type *parr = (type[]){__VA_ARGS__}; \
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) \
        arr[i] = *parr++; }
```

It's not safe (no bounds checking), overwrites only consecutive members starting from the beginning but I find it useful sometimes.

Complete example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define arr_set(type, arr, ...) { \
    int arr_size = sizeof((type[]){__VA_ARGS__}) / sizeof(type); \
    type *parr = (type[]){__VA_ARGS__}; \
    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) \
        arr[i] = *parr++; }

#define print_buf_int(buf) { \
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]); i++) \
        printf("%d ", (int)buf[i]); \
    printf("\n"); }

#define print_buf_char(buf) { \
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]); i++) \
        if (buf[i]) \
            printf("%c ", (char)buf[i]); \
        else \
            printf("null "); \
    printf("\n"); }

#define print_buf_str(buf) { \
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]); i++) \
        printf("%s ", (char*)buf[i]); \
    printf("\n"); }

int main()
{
    int brr[8] = {};
    int arr[8] = {3, 4, 5, 1, 0, 2};
    print_buf_int(arr);

    arr_set(int, arr, 9, 8 ,7);
    print_buf_int(arr);

    arr_set(int, arr, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    print_buf_int(arr);

    arr_set(int, arr, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99);  // 'brr' gets overwritten!!!
    print_buf_int(arr);
    print_buf_int(brr);

    unsigned char crr[13] = {'a', 'b', 'c', [12] = 'z'};
    print_buf_char(crr);

    arr_set(char, crr, 'd', 'e', 'f', '1', '2', '3');
    print_buf_char(crr);

    unsigned short srr[] = {111, 222, 333, 444, 555};
    print_buf_int(srr);

    arr_set(unsigned short, srr, -1, 0, 666);
    print_buf_int(srr);

    char *prr[] = {"hello", "variadic", "world"};
    print_buf_str(prr);

    arr_set(char*, prr, "good", "bye");
    print_buf_str(prr);
}
```

Output:

```
3 4 5 1 0 2 0 0 
9 8 7 1 0 2 0 0 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 
99 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
a b c null null null null null null null null null z 
d e f 1 2 3 null null null null null null z 
111 222 333 444 555 
65535 0 666 444 555 
hello variadic world 
good bye world
```